# Ext: How to evaluate incoming inputs?

Tags: extjs

How to evaluate incoming inputs? Below is how I`m trying to get the JSon input:

```
var store =new Ext.data.Store({
        autoLoad : true,
        proxy : new Ext.data.HttpProxy({
            url: '../../../SomeWebService/Service.svc/XmlToJSON/0',
            method: 'POST'
        }),
        reader: new Ext.data.JsonReader(
            {
                id: '_id',
                root: 'ROOT.I',
                totalProperty: 'total',
                successProperty: 'success'
            }, 
            record
        )/* ,
        data:data  */
    });
```

Below is output of web-service i am getting as a string/text:

```
"{ \"Doc\": {\"I\": {\"ID\": \"1010\", \"ID1\": \"True\", \"ID2\": \"-1\", \"ID3\": \"1\", \"FD\": \"10\", \"ID4\": \"mm\" } }}"
```

My actual input has to be like :

```
"{ "Doc": {"I": {"ID": "1010", "ID1": "True", "ID2": "-1", "ID3": "1", "FD": "10", "ID4": "mm" } }}"
```

but reader is not reading this output of web-service,
Please help.

Comment: The output doesn't make any sense in a store setup.

Comment: Can you explain how you want the output to look as a model or as a row in a grid visually to me?

Comment: output string is what i m getting as a output of web-service( as text/string), which the json-reader is not able to read

Comment: I understand that, how do you want that string to look in a table structure on your web app?

Comment: there will be a ext-js grid with few columns , each expecting data from/of ID,ID1,ID2.. attributes respectively

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a problem with the `return type of webservice`. So instead of returning the string directly, you may use like this

```
WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";             
return new MemoryStream(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(strjson));
```